# Better A* Search Heuristic in a 2-d grid world

Tags: a-star, heuristics

I am still new with the idea of A* Search. I understand some of the Heuristic that A* Search have such as Straight-Line Distance (Euclidean Distance), Manhattan Distance and Misplaced Tiles (for 8 puzzle game).

For the 2-d grid world,
Which is better admissible heuristic than Straight-Line Distance. I have my mind on Manhattan Distance. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I hope that you know what does heuristic means...

Comment: @eliasah i know slightly. I am still learning

Comment: Then here is where you should start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_(computer_science) . Once you understand what heuristics are you'll probably figure out the answer to your question alone! :)

Comment: It depends on how the character can move. If diagonal movement isn't allowed, then the distance between two points is the Manhattan distance. If diagonal movement is possible, then it's the Chebyshev distance.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo so are you saying that if diagonal movement is not allowed, manhattan distance will be better than straight line distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using A* there are two properties that must hold for the heuristic, in order for the search to be optimal (finding the best solution).

- The heuristic must be admissible
- The heuristic must be monotonistic

In reality it's pretty hard to come up with a non-monotonistic (also called inconsistent) heuristic, so lets stick with the first requirement.

A heuristic is admissible if it never *overestimates* the distance between two nodes (in this case points). As such the manhattan-distance heuristic is *not* admissible if diagonal movements are allowed - simply because of pythagoras theorem (the combined length of the two catheti, is longer than the squareroot of the hypothenuse), so in this case the straight line distance heuristic is the better - since it's admissible.

However if diagonal movements are not allowed in the 2D grid, then both heuristics are admissible, since neither will overestimate the distance, but hte manhattan distance heuristic is the preferred, because it makes better estimates, i.e. estimates closer to the actual distance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a heuristic that agrees with the allowed movement:

- For **4-directions**, use Manhattan distance (L1)
- For **8-directions**, use Chebyshev distance ([L-Infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance))
- For **any direction**, you *can* use Euclidean distance, but an alternative map representation may be better (e.g. using Waypoints)

Amit Patel has produced fantastic reference material for this subject. See his page at [RedBlobGames.com](http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html) for an introduction to A* and his page on Stanford's [Game Programming Page](http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/) for a description of several grid-world Heuristics . His Stanford page also describes several methods for reducing size of the open set when optimality is not required.

There are also extensions for A* to take advantage of symmetry in grids with constant movement cost. Daniel Harabor introduced two in his doctoral thesis--Jump Point Search (JPS) and Rectangular Symmetry Reduction (RSR). He describes these in an article he posted on [AiGameDev.com](http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/symmetry-in-pathfinding/)